# Combining columns one by one from three dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have three dataframes, for example, the first one has the variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3`. The second has `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, and the last one has `z1`, `z2`, `z3` columns. I want to create a dataframe with the order like this:

```
x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3
```

```
x1 <- c(1:10)
x2 <- c(1:10)
x3 <- c(11:20)
x <- data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))

y1 <- c(1:10)
y2 <- c(1:10)
y3 <- c(11:20)
y <- data.frame(cbind(y1,y2,y3))

z1 <- c(1:10)
z2 <- c(1:10)
z3 <- c(11:20)
z <- data.frame(cbind(z1,z2,z3))
```

The three dataframes have more columns (15), I want the one with the ones, the second with the seconds...

Comment: can u put ur data and ur code what u have try

Comment: please make your question reproducible. What length are the dataframes? Do they have a common key (ID column) that can be used to merge them? if not, `rbind` them. Also include what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have equal number of rows in each dataframe, you could `cbind` them, remove the characters and use `order`

```
df <- cbind(df1, df2, df3)
df[, order(gsub("[A-Za-z]", "", names(df)))]

#  x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3
#1  1  1  1  6  6  6 11 11 11
#2  2  2  2  7  7  7 12 12 12
#3  3  3  3  8  8  8 13 13 13
#4  4  4  4  9  9  9 14 14 14
#5  5  5  5 10 10 10 15 15 15
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 6:10, x3 = 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(y1 = 1:5, y2 = 6:10, y3 = 11:15)
df3 <- data.frame(z1 = 1:5, z2 = 6:10, z3 = 11:15)
```